# How to be notified when contact has been edited on custom store on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, store, contacts

I'm facing some serious problem here:
I'm creating a Windows Phone 8 application that handles contact synchronization, but I'm unable to tell if a local contact should be updated on the server since I found nothing to notify my app that a contact in my contact store has been edited (using native contacts app).

I'd need something like a revision number.
What I found so far is the ContactChangeRecord class but it needs a contact store revision, and mine seems to be always the same one, even after a contact changed (1).

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Revision number is one of the properties of contact store class. There is also some kind of "journal" where you can check type of operations.

Answer (score 0):

The revision number of the Contact store should change.You can detect any changes made in your contactStore:

```
ContactStore cloudContactStore = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite, ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.ReadOnly);

     // Assuming you already have created the contactStore and made some changes from the 
     // device like deleting, or renaming a contact
        var changeList = await cloudContactStore.GetChangesAsync(5);

        foreach (var change in changeList)
        {
            // Each change record returned contains the change type, remote and local ids, and revision number
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Change Type: {0}\nLocal ID: {1}\nRemote ID: {2}\nRevision Number: {3}",
                change.ChangeType.ToString(),
                change.Id,
                await remoteIDHelper.GetUntaggedRemoteId(cloudContactStore, change.RemoteId),
                change.RevisionNumber));
            // Get the contact associated with the change record using the Id property.
            var contact = await cloudContactStore.FindContactByIdAsync(change.Id);
            if (contact != null)
            {
            }
        }
```

Check the debug output of Visual Studio. You should see the contact id with the type of changes made (Created, Modified, Deleted)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.personalinformation.contactchangetype.aspx

Have a look at this sample : http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/3D34679D/F29F8FA4 for further details